# How to save and restore workspace in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, workspaces

I tried using the extension **Auto move windows** but it didn't help my requirement. Soon after i turn off and turn on my laptop again, the workspace and the applications I opened prior are all gone. I have to again re-arrange all my workspaces. Pls, help me to solve this issue.

Comment: **Auto Move Windows** has a bug. If you've configured it, and `Startup Applications`, log in, wait for the applications to launch, then manually select each Workspace, and the app windows will move to the desired Workspace.

Comment: I do not experience the bug you mention @heynnema. The extension works perfectly fine in v20.04 and as expected as set out in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may have missed the final step in the equation.

The next step is to setup in `Startup Applications` the applications you wish to load on startup of your PC and to set up in the extension the Workspace you wish to associate the application with.

[image]

[image]

You can access `Startup Applications` by pressing the left <kbd>windows</kbd> key - also known as the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and in the search tool bar enter `Startup` and select it from there. The `Configure this extension` icon allows you to complete the process for the extension.

Note that in the above graphics, `Auto Move Windows` contains an entry for `Chromium Web Browser` but that is not included in `Startup Applications` as a result of which it does not get loaded at startup - which is directly the effect you are experiencing.

[image]

Comment: *"left Windows key"* should be **Super key** in Ubuntu talk.

Comment: @heynnema thank you for the clarification. I have added that to my answer.

Comment: @24601 Tq for answering my question. I have small requriement here: I have combination of chrome windows, vscode and terminal in one workspace which i cannot assing in the **AUTO MOVE WINDOWS** extension. It allows only to add one application in one workspace which is not my requirement.